# Tag List Template Global Setting is Ignored

Tags: joomla-3.x, overrides, tags, template-override

**My goal:** change the layout of my front page which is a menu item of the type 'tag list' (or something similar, don't know the precise translation). As usual, I made a file overriding the view template which creates the respective section.

**What I've done:** So I've made a file `<template>/html/com_tags/tag/default_items.php` with the same contents as `components/com_tags/views/tag/tmpl/default_items.php`, expecting to see any changes I make to the aforementioned file. However, even if I empty the file, the result is the same as without the file alltogether.

---

**EDIT - UPDATE 1:** As suggested in an answer, I have tried creating an alternative layout instead. So I made the file `<template>/html/com_tags/tag/custom_layout_test.php` and put a test string in it, but I cannot select it in the admin interface's `template style` option of the menu entry.

---

**EDIT - UPDATE 2:** Well, it still does not work, but I have found [this](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/13583/how-to-show-tagged-items-in-category-blog-layout), which is precisely what I wanted to do anyways. Thanks for your attempts to help me, I guess I missed something, but I don't really have any more time on this. Sorry for leaving this open, maybe the link will help someone.

Answer (score 2):

I just asked Google 'joomla tag list override' and it told me: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=706&t=854545

Edit - Update 1:
Copy `components/com_tags/views/tag/tmpl/default.php` and rename it to
`<template>/html/com_tags/tag/namewithoutunderscores.php`.

Then copy `<template>/html/com_tags/tag/default_items.php` to
`components/com_tags/views/tag/tmpl/default_items.php` and edit it to your liking.

Then you should set alternative tag list layout 'namewithoutunderscores' as default in Tagged Items Options.

Comment: thank you, I've read that link already. They said to rename default.php and not use default_items.php at all. If I understand correctly, they're creating an _alternative_ layout, not altering the default layout. Am I missing something?

Comment: You should create alternative layout and set it as default in Tagged Items Options.

Comment: Please see my edit, that didn't work out as it was described. I feel like I'm asking very dumb questions, I just don't get why it's not working though. I mean I've done this for an extension's components already, I don't know what's different here.

Comment: thanks for the update. My "default.php" is now called `testname.php` and I can select `testname` in the global config for tag views, but it doesn't seem to change anything. Now I'm completely confused

Comment: Then its beyond my reach, sorry and good luck.