# More on tags in category blog layout

Tags: menu-item, tags, category-blog

I have been trying to create a menu item that shows all articles in category blog layout for tags. I followed webchun's instructions here:

[How to show tagged items in category blog layout](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/13583/how-to-show-tagged-items-in-category-blog-layout)

(which it won't let me add more to the question because it's locked)

I got it to work, even got the read more button added (though I don't think correctly, because it doesn't check if there is a read more just automatically adds it), but what I need is to add other elements to it which are not options. I want to add the published date, the author, and the category. I know that this is an override, but I have no idea what parts to copy. I tried copying somethings from blog_items.php under my (custom) template, but it just stopped the page from loading).

Answer (score 1):

Open taggedblog_items.php

Within your foreach loop you need to access the object variable that you desire and wrap it in html code.

For example:

`<div class="foo"><?php echo $item->created; ?></div>`

`<div class="foo"><?php echo $item->author_name; ?></div>`

`<div class="foo"><?php echo $item->category_title; ?></div>`

These values are based on the joomla v3.51 com_content item object, so if you are using an older version the values may be different. To check what values you need put 
`die("<pre>".print_r($item, true)."</pre>");` within your foreach loop and try to access your site. You should see something like this.

`stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 20
    [title] => Acquisition
    [alias] => acquisition
    [checked_out] => 172
    [checked_out_time] => 2016-05-16 19:34:26
    [catid] => 8
    [state] => 1
    [access] => 1
    [created] => 2016-05-03 21:32:09
    [created_by] => 172
    [created_by_alias] => 
    [ordering] => 0
    [featured] => 0
    [language] => *
    [hits] => 0
    [publish_up] => 2016-05-03 21:32:09
    [publish_down] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    [language_title] => 
    [language_image] => 
    [editor] => Super User
    [access_level] => Public
    [category_title] => Acquisition
    [author_name] => Super User
    [max_ordering] => 0
)`

If the values are different then switch them out and you should get the results you want.