# Tagged items blog layout

Tags: joomla-3.x, template-override, tags, category-blog

This has come up before but I don't have enough reputation to comment into the original questions.

User [webchun](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/users/2295/webchun) gave a great tutorial in [How to show tagged items in category blog layout](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/13583/how-to-show-tagged-items-in-category-blog-layout) which works really well, but he wrote it referencing Joomla 3.4.4 and the templates have changed in the new releases.

Using his method, I got a much nicer blog layout, but each item is displaying twice. Has anyone else had any luck developing this further?

Answer (score 2):

This is now a core feature in Joomla 3.8, i.e. filtering articles category blog layout with tags.

Comment: Yes it's a core feature but it's not a TAG page feature I believe.