# Tagged blog layout with readmore

Tags: overrides, tags, readmore

I implemented the solution that enables a blog layout for tagged items, as described here: 
[How to show tagged items in category blog layout](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/13583/how-to-show-tagged-items-in-category-blog-layout)

What I miss is the Read More button.

How do I implement that?

Comment: I made something that works by adding this to the taggedblog_item.php:
`<p class="readmore">
   <a class="btn readmore-link"  href="<?php echo JRoute::_(TagsHelperRoute::getItemRoute($item->content_item_id, $item->core_alias, $item->core_catid, $item->core_language, $item->type_alias, $item->router)); ?>">
   <?php echo 'Lees meer: ' ?>
   <?php echo $this->escape($item->core_title); ?>
   </a></p>`

Comment: Please understand, that the Stack Exchange Network has a rather consistent page format that is unlike forums and other chronologically listed postings.  As you would have read while taking the [tour], a single page should have one question with all details in the body's text, and potentially multiple posted answers.  Comments should be used by volunteers to seek clarification from the asker or possibly offer non-resolving advice.  You must not post solutions as comments because this breaks SE page design and requires future researchers to look for specific content in unexpected places.

Comment: Please post your commented solution as an answer to enjoy superior formatting tools and be as generous as possible with your explanation so that you help as many future researchers as possible.  By posting as an answer (versus a comment), you stand to earn upvotes and unlock more privileges which will help you to have a more robust and enjoyable experience here in the future (e.g. the ads go away once you reach a certain rep threshold.) After posting your answer, you will be able to mark this page as resolved with the green tick, it can be moved if another answer proves superior in the future.