# How to show tagged items in category blog layout and adjust the photo size

Tags: tags, layout

I am following the advice from
[How to show tagged items in category blog layout](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/13583/how-to-show-tagged-items-in-category-blog-layout).

It works, but I'm having a problem with the photos.
The photos are being shown twice -- one below the other.

I would also like to ask if there is any way to adjust the photo size.

Comment: Welcome to JSE, please take our [tour].  It might be helpful for us to see some of your code and for us to know which pieces of advice you are using from the other page.

Comment: thank you so much for the reply!!!
I quote the link https://socialo.gr/video-35

Comment: Could you post the code (in full) of the overrides that you're using? Also what you have tried in order to fix the problem. You can adjust photo sizes using CSS - have you looked into that?

Answer (score 1):

In "taggedblog_items.php", there is some code that needs to be removed or commented out in order to get rid of the duplicate image (and duplicate intro text).  But how you do this will depend on whether you want to keep toggle control available in the admin or just hardcode it to do want you want.

Keep the toggles...

- Remove lines 51-65

Hardcode it...

- Remove lines 45-50
- Remove lines 66-72

Comment: Welcome to JSE, Brady and thank you for contributing.  Please take our [tour] and consider introducing yourself by adding something to your profile.  Regarding this answer, it will be clearer to the OP and researchers if you explicitly indicate the actual code that should be removed instead of just the line numbers.  As Joomla versions, change, the line numbers may become out of sync with your answer.  You can [edit] this answer whenever and as often as you like.