# Joomla 3: Display tags as a Category Blog

Tags: tags, category-blog

Is it possible to create a menu item type -> Tags list BUT display as a Category Blog?

I want to display a list of articles of the same tag in the same way as a category blog, that is, not just a list of article titles but the full articles (text, intro image, info, content, etc).

Comment: Do you mean like here: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/13583/how-to-show-tagged-items-in-category-blog-layout

Comment: Welcome to JSE and thank you for your question @Filippos.  Please take our [tour] and respond to astridx's comment.  If the suggested page resolves your question, then we can close this page as a duplicate.  If not, then please [edit] your question to isolate how your question is different or how you are not able to implement the pre-existing advice.

Comment: yes, you're right. Problem solved.